# Flyway Java migrations not working in command line tool

Tags: java, command-line, flyway

I just cannot get Java migrations get to be recognized and executed using the flyway command line tool.

What I did so far:

1. Download and extract Flyway (commandline version)
2. Configured flyway.properties in the conf directory, setting the following properties

   - flyway.driver, flyway.url, flyway.user, flyway.password
3. Added oracle JDBC driver to the jars directory
4. Executed flyway.cmd init => Worked. History table was created.
5. Added an SQL File to the ./sql directory V1_1__Some_sql.sql
6. Executed flyway.cmd migrate => worked. DB was changed

   FINE SO FAR. Works as expected. Now the problematic part:
7. Created a Java class in my IDE.

   ```
   public class V1_2__Another_test implements JdbcMigration 
   {

      public void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception 
      {

         PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO flyway_sample (name) VALUES ('My Name')");

         try {
            statement.execute();
         } finally {
            statement.close();
         }
      }
   }
   ```
8. Compiled the class, put it into a jar with name V1_2__Another_test.jar
9. Placed the jar in sql or jars and tried to run flyway.cmd migrate. => Flyway ignores it.
10. Tried to put the .class file into jars or sql => Flyway also ignores it.
11. I use Flyway 2.1.1.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

What you did sounds fine. Make sure to add the package where your class resides to flyway.locations and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you, giving packagenames to flyway.locations was the missing part. Now it seems to work.

Comment: I have mentioned the location. still it dos not working. `flyway.jarDirs=D:/Software/dbmigrationtool/flyway-4.0/jars
flyway.locations=classpath:db.migration,filesystem:D:/Workspace/Commercial/commercial/CCPlatform/src/main/database/oracle/update_tanant`

Comment: I have a similar problem using flyway with Springboot 2.2.  Flyway cannot detect my java migration file when I execute the command `mvn flyway:info`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below line from `flyway.conf` file. It would work post that.

```
flyway.jarDirs=None
```